# Is there a subtle difference between "somebody" and "someone", "anybody" and "anyone"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, pronouns, one-body

Are there any subtle differences between "somebody" and "someone", or can they be used completely interchangeably? Similarly, can you imagine a situation in which you would prefer "anybody" to "anyone" or vice versa?

Comment: These two words are synonymous; you can use either interchangeably. They *might* have very slightly different connotations depending on the context in which they are used, but I can't think of an  example that couldn't be as easily attributed to my own imagination.

Comment: Prior to the name "Beuller", you must use "anyone". Otherwise, you can use either.

Comment: @David: Could you please explain your "Beuller" exception?

Comment: @Gnubie: Either Google "anyone bueller", watch [`Ferris Bueller's Day Off`](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091042/), or watch [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEXfASbPbDM).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Nice, except that those lines don't actually come together in the movie.

Comment: I think a polish politician was ridiculed for opening a meeting of the EU parliament with "Welcome everybody!" - such an extremely official situation will rather require "Everyone".

Answer (score 26):

There is little or no difference between the *-one* and *-body* variants.

However, there is a major difference between *somebody* and *anybody*--*anybody* is one of the "negative valency" words in English, which is required when the main verb of the sentence is negated.

> I haven't seen anybody. [Correct]
>
> **!** I haven't seen somebody. [Incorrect]

Conversely, in sentences in which the main verb is affirmative (not negated), the preferred pronoun should be *somebody* and not *anybody*.

> I saw somebody in the hall. [Correct]
>
> **!** I saw anybody in the hall. [Incorrect]

In subject position, you should prefer *somebody* when a particular person is implied, although you don't know who it is. *Anybody* can be used when you have no particular person in mind.

> Somebody called me on the phone. [Correct]
>
> **!** Anybody called me on the phone. [Incorrect]
>
> **?** Somebody can come to the party. [Not exactly incorrect, but very strange--it implies that there is a single, unnamed person that can come to the party.]
>
> Anybody can come to the party. [Correct]

Comment: Oh well, thanks for the effort, but that's a rather huge footnote following the first paragraph. I'd limit it to "However, there is a major difference between *some-* and *any-*." to keep the discussion on topic.

Comment: I would note also that questions have negative polarity, so you use the *any-* variants in questions too: “Have you seen anybody?”; “Did you see anybody in the hall?”; “Did anybody call you on the phone?”

Comment: @JSBձոգչ "Can *anybody/somebody* explain the principles of democracy?" What about this sentence?

Comment: @Sudhir, why don't you post that as a separate question?

Comment: I think that one way to look at it is that "anybody" is an **abstract concept** whereas "somebody" is more concrete - it refers to an actual person.  So the reason that "I saw somebody in the hall" works is that you saw an actual real thing, and the reason that "I saw anybody in the hall." **doesn't** work is that you're claiming to have seen an *absract concept*.

Answer (score 10):

Here's what *Garner's Modern American Usage* says:

> The two terms are interchangeable, so euphony governs the choice in any given context. In practice, *anyone* appears in print about three times as often as *anybody*.

Answer (score 7):

While M-W doesn't provide any hints on difference between the two, my understanding is that *someone* is used more for hinting at a particular person, for sarcasm or otherwise.

E.g. I don't think I've ever heard the phrase "special somebody", as opposed to "special someone". *Somebody* sounds more generic.

Comment: "Special somebody" sounds OK to me. A quick Google search reveals a few uses of the phrase.

Comment: Yes, but still it's 43k to 2.4M in favor of "someone". And of course, not everyone is a native speaker (neither am I), but I don't claim "special somebody" is wrong. 

I believe language is too elastic to faithfully and exactly track minor meaning differences like this in dictionaries, but I think it's safe to say that "special someone" is a more popular phrase than "special somebody", as Google result count shows.

Comment: I believe that "special someone" may be more felicitous just for prosodic reasons - "special someone" is two trochees, while "special somebody" doesn't follow a regular rhythm.

Comment: (not a native speaker)*  I agree. I'd tend to use "somebody" in contexts when the person is not known to me/speaker, while "someone" is favored in general contexts or when mentioning the person understood as "someone" is for some reason avoided. Examples provided on the Cambridge Dictionary website here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/someone-somebody-something-somewhere seem to support this point: I know someone who gives piano lessons. (a specific person) Somebody has obviously made a mistake. (general, we don’t know who).

Comment: I can't explain precisely why, but I'd probably exclusively use "someone" when I'm implying something like "I know who but I won't tell (because it doesn't matter or it won't do much to the listener if I said the name). Ngram for "someone told me, somebody told me", for example, might be indicating this tendency, I'm not sure https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=somebody+told+me%2Csomeone+told+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csomebody%20told%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csomeone%20told%20me%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I heard explanation given by a writer that , quote, we say "one" to designate a singular, unique person, even if it stays unnamed or unknown, quote. Anyone becomes 'any other "one"' and everyone is 'every "one" available'.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what Michael Swan says on this matter in his book, Practical English Usage (Swan 2005, OUP):

"There is no significant difference between *somebody* and *someone*, *anybody* and *anyone*, *everybody* and *everyone* or nobody and *no one.* **The -one forms are more common in writing; the -body forms are more frequent in speech in British English**" [emphasis mine - Alex B.] (p. 548).

Answer (score 5):

The variations ending in "-body" tend to sound less formal than "-one." Which one you use would depend on your audience.

Answer (score 1):

In the *New Oxford American Dictionary*, both the words are used to mean *person of importance or authority* (*a small-time lawyer keen to be someone*; *I'd like to be somebody*; *nobodies who want to become somebodies*); in definition of *somebody*, it's reported that it means *some person* or *someone*.

Answer (score 0):

I think nowadays they're perfect synonyms. Trying to find a difference would be like trying to find an inner meaning to some weird movie which the producer made just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

*Anybody* and *anyone* are completely synonymous and there's really nothing more to tell.

Comment: That describes my intuition as well, but only a close examination of the relevant corpora would provide the evidence one way or another.