# Does "anything man" exist?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, nouns

Is *anything man* a word (noun)?

Is there a synonym or a better word?

[Context](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Robert_Scoble&oldid=442180305#Career) (my emphasis):

> After college he was working for Fawcette Technical Publications (as **anything man** - design, editing, helping plan the conferences like VBITS and VSLive!).

Comment: It's definitely not *a word*, as it's at least two words.

Comment: @JSBangs: what is the correct term then? Compound word? Compound noun? Idiom?

Comment: @JSBangs: Doesn't that depend on your definition of "word"? I believe many phrases are conveniently called "words" in certain contexts, such as *post office, fool proof*, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though *anything man* is not a common term, some good [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/jack-of-all-trades?__utma=1.669797498.1311164655.1312032540.1312033334.32&__utmb=1.13.9.1312033598558&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1312032540.31.26.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=oneself%7Cutmcct=/&__utmv=-&__utmk=48645542) are:

- [jack-of-all-trades](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jack-of-all-trades) - *a person who is adept at many different kinds of work.*
- [factotum](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/factotum) - *1. a person, as a handyman or servant, employed to do all kinds of work around the house. 2. any employee or official having many different responsibilities.*
- [handyman](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/handyman) - *a person hired to do various small Jobs [sic], especially in the maintenance of an apartment building, office building, or the like.*
- [tinker](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tinker) - *3. a person skilled in various minor kinds of mechanical work; jack-of-all-trades.*

Comment: I believed Dictionary.com at first for *proteus* and *pantologist*, but vetoed them after seeing their definition.

Comment: Also [chief cook and bottle washer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chief_cook_and_bottle_washer), which notwithstanding Wikipedia's definition, I don't particularly associate with being "the boss" so much as "the poor sod who has to do just about everything".

Comment: *Jack of all trades* has a negative connotation to it, generally being seen in the sentence *Jack of all trades, master of none*.

Comment: I think *factotum* comes closest, given the context. However [Wiktionary says "dated"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/factotum#Noun).

Comment: There's also *gofer,* which is someone who does assorted unskilled tasks, although the word the OP wants would need more skilled work than a gofer usually does.

Comment: @nico: I disagree. [This site](http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2007/09/14/the-top-5-reasons-to-be-a-jack-of-all-trades/) is the fourth result of googling *jack-of-all-trades* (the first two refer to Wikipedia's *Jack of all trades, master of none* page).  Almost every time I've seen it used, it was used without a trace of negativity.

Comment: @drm: I mostly heard it associated with *master of none*. However I agree that it can be used without any negative acception. I would however prefer *factotum* in that case.

Comment: @nico: I personally love that word, and keep wondering why it's not used more often.

Answer (score 2):

"Anything man" is not an established idiom that I've ever heard. However, within the context that you've provided its meaning is readily deduced as referring to someone who does *anything*, so I would say that you should feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Polymath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath) instead, it is much nicer. Also according to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/is-there-a-subtle-difference-between-somebody-and-someone) even if it was possible to have such phrase then it would be "Everything Man" but not "Anything Man"

Comment: A *polymath* doesn't have the connotation of being an employee.

Comment: @Peter : Aaargh, should have paid attention to the context emphesis, thanks Peter.

Comment: *Polymath assistant* might work, but I like *anything man* better.

Answer (score 0):

What about handyman?

> handyman (noun) - a man skilled in various odd jobs and other small tasks.