# Do you make a difference between “anybody” and “anyone”

Tags: meaning, synonyms, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a subtle difference between “somebody” and “someone”, “anybody” and “anyone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/is-there-a-subtle-difference-between-somebody-and-someone-anybody-and-an)

Not being an English native, I’m totally unable to distinguish between the two words. Is there any difference? Could you use one instead of the other at any time?